# Pandas computing average mean and stdev

Tags: python, pandas, mean, standard-deviation

My goal is to compute the mean and standard deviation of different samples.  For example, I have a df:

```
Start   End   n     Mean   Dev
abc     x     54     47    5
abc     x     45     42    4
abc     y     14     50    10
abc     y     16     30    20
ijk     x     25     20    5
ijk     x     25     20    5
ijk     z     7      10    2
```

Output:

```
Start   End   N     CombinedMean   CombinedDev
abc     x     99    44.7           5.2
abc     y     30    39.3           19
ijk     x     50    20             5
ijk     z     7     10             2
```

Normally I would use groupby and agg({'N': 'sum', 'Mean':'mean', 'Dev':'mean'}) but this is mathematically incorrect.  To compute the combined mean and deviation in this case I have to use:

```
CombinedMean = sum(n*mean)/Sum(n)

CombinedDev = sqrt[ sum(n*(dev^2+mean^2))/sum(n) - (combined mean)^2]
```

For example,

```
N = n1+n2 = 54+45 = 99

Sum = n1*mean1 + n2*mean2 = 54*47+45*42 = 4,428

The combined mean is Sum / N = 4,428 / 99 = 44.7

Sum of Squares = n1*(sd1^2 + mean1^2) + n2*(sd2^2 + mean2^2) = 54*(5^2 + 47^2) + 45*(4^2 + 42^2) = 200,736

So the combined standard deviation is SQRT(Sum of Squares / N - Mean^2) = SQRT(200,739/99 - 44.7^2) = 5.2
```

Long question short:  how can I implement the 2 formulas in my code?  Many thanks!  My apology for the lengthy question :)

Comment: You can def your own function and using lambda with agg

Comment: @Wen How would I do that?  Don't I need to group first?

Comment: You need groupby here  , def your own function which include those calculation you need ,  then with df.groupby ().agg()

Comment: @TylerNG, have a go at using `lambda`. There are examples in the marked duplicate.